# STM32 F103 GPIO software toggling too slow for 20 microseconds state change?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, atmega, motor-controller, gpio

I'm designing an ESC for my hobby project but I got stuck on current chopping. I want to toggle a pin every 20 us and want to use a timer interrupt for this. On the oscilloscope I can see that timer output pin is capable of toggling even faster than this, but when I place `HAL_GPIO_TOGGLE` insinde timer interrupt routine the pin switches with 600 us rate (which is way too slow).
I really want to understand why is it so?
Also I would like to is it even possible to achive (and how) such toggling speed when when using state change in software?
[image: Waveforms]

And this is the code that drives the pin, called every 20 us:

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
       HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(UH_GPIO_Port, UH_Pin);
}
```

I could understand some delay but not this big.
I have already tried not using `HAL_GPIO_TOGGLE` but rather setting individual bits in `BSRR` register but i didn't see any improvement.
The ESC itself is designed right, because i can make the motor spin without current chopping (but power supply is in CC mode).
I'm using STM32  [F103RB-NUCLEO](https://os.mbed.com/platforms/ST-Nucleo-F103RB/) board (8 MHz clock), but maybe i need to change to some other MCU. I know that they use atmega or silabs chips in commercial ESCs but I think F103 is perfectly capable of driving my circuit.

Comment: You’ve not told us the actual clock rate of the cpu - your software determines this. Nevertheless, you’re working the cpu hard to generate these 20us pulses. Normally you’d use the timer to generate the pulses using its hardware modes rather than using interrupts.

Comment: I'm totally new to programming STM32, but the system clock is 8 MHz (using HSI). I know 20 us maybe quite fast but when I looked at some commercial ESCs I could see Atmega8 which has an internal clock of 8 MHz so i guess F103 should handle driving the ESC too?

Comment: Using that library code won’t be helping, but is there a good reason to use software for this rather than just getting a timer to toggle it for you? Also your microcontroller can run at 72 MHz using the HSI with its PLL which may help with your quest.

Comment: Your scope is showing channel 1 toggling every 20us. Where is this measured and what's wrong with using it as it is? There's nothing wrong with using `HAL_GPIO_TogglePin()` as it's just a simple macro, but *why* do you particularly want to toggle the pin in software instead of using the timer hardware to do it for you?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion with PLL, just tried it, but it is not enough. 
 Well the application kind of forces me to control individual pins. The other thing is I have seen a similar project on YT, where Arduino Nano is used and pins are controlled individually (the timer only choose when to switch the high side pin low), so I assumed it is possible this way. Do you think using multiple channels  on a single timer and starting/stopping it would be better soultion?

Comment: Using a hardware module to perform a function instead of writing software to perform the same function is a better solution 99% of the time. IMO you'd need a really good reason not to. Check the [micro's documentation](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/cd00171190-stm32f101xx-stm32f102xx-stm32f103xx-stm32f105xx-and-stm32f107xx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) to see if you can use a timer which supports 'complementary outputs' which will switch both high-side & low-side for you, even with a programmable dead-time.

Comment: It seems simply not possible. To run a piece of code every 20ns you would need a clock with f>=50MHz. That is assuming you only need one instruction to toggle the pin. But your interrupt ("timer elapsed callback") will almost certainly need >5 instructions just to reach your code to toggle the pin. Plus toggling the pin almost certainly will need a load and a store instruction as well. You should check with your debugger how many instructions are actually required to toggle the pin from inside your ISR.

Comment: @markus-nm It is 20 **µs**, not 20 **ns**. Anyway, your proposal to look at the assembly is one of the best so far.

Comment: I'm going to try both assembly and complementary PWM. Still I'm confused about how a cheap ESC from Hobbyking with Atmega can perform better than my circuit. Feels like I'm missing something obvious. Thanks for the help so far, I've made some slight progress.